# Can I install several files into one artifact with Maven2 instal:install-file command

Tags: maven-2, maven-install-plugin

I'm developping application with JOGL2 and my favorite IDE Eclipse, also I want to use Maven2 for this purpose. Unfortunately, JOGL2 has no artifact yet. Also, I plan to deploy it as a runnable jar file.

So I want to install JOGL artifact locally : so i'll use the install:install-file command.

But I want to group several jars to make several artifacts, that is :

- gluegen-rt.jar and jogl.all.jar as a single artifact named jogl.core
- gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar and jogl.all-natives-linux-i586.jar as a single jar named jogl-natives-linux-i586
- and so on

Is it possible ? (The official documentation does not mention the possibility or unpossibility to do so).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install all files as usual like `file:jar:version`. Than create pom with `pom` packaging and  use `gluegen-rt.jar` and `jogl.all.jar` as dependencies in it (they must be already installed). After that use new pom as dependency in your project.

Comment: +1, OP asks for a single JAR, but your suggestion is actually better

Comment: Thank you :) Looks quite promising : but I don't understand procedure of the second sentence. Please, tell me more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692161/what-is-pom-packaging-in-maven
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075285/why-maven-compilation-doesnt-work-with-pom-packaging-type

Comment: 1. Install your files as usual `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar`

2. Create new pom.xml, with: `groupId=jogl`, `artifactId=core`, `version=1.0-MY-CUSTOM-JOGL`, `packaging=pom` (for example)

3. Add dependencies to this pom in `dependencies` section

4. Run `mvn clean install` in directory with new pom

5. Use dependency `jogl:core:1.0-MY-CUSTOM-JOGL` in your project

6. Should work :), i'm writing by memory, but the idea is that.

Comment: This will still bring in your two jars as separate. If you want to create a single jar do what madhead suggests but switch the packaging to jar and use the maven assembly plugin to generate the combined artifact.

Answer (score 2):

maven doesn't have support for that. You would have to unpack these JAR files and repackage them together.

maven *does* have support for merging JAR with dependencies (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594) - and it's done the way I mentioned above. But you are asking about merging two arbitrary JARs, which is not possible in maven.